# What are the ways to check a process with specific pid exists and active?

Tags: c, linux

What are the ways to check a process with specific pid exists and active (not zombie)?
I am using Ubuntu Linux with gcc.

Comment: Not sure what an "active" process is, do you mean "not zombie"?

Comment: Most such information is contained in the `/proc` set of directories

Answer (score 3):

You should understand that by the time you decide to something with this process, it may be long gone (google [TOCTOU](https://www.google.com/search?q=toctou)).

Anyway, the POSIX way is to call `kill (0, pid)` and check the `errno`. `ESRCH` would mean "no such process" and `EPERM` is "the process exists but you cannot signal it".

A Linux-specific way would be reading the `/proc` directory. Entries there correspond to PIDs (there are also some entries which are not numeric, you can ignore them). Not all Linux systems use `/proc` though.

If you are using SELINUX there might be processes you are not allowed to even know about, but since you can't do much about it, don't even worry.